# Zottffssentettffssen

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Print or return the following string:

```
zottffssentettffssenttttttttttttttttttttffffffffffffffffffffsssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeennnnnnnnnno
```

This is the first letter of each of the numbers **z**ero, **o**ne, **t**wo, all the way up to **o**ne hundred.

Standard I/O rules apply, but the output must be exactly as shown above, optionally with a single trailing newline. No other variation in output is permitted. This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.

---

<sup>Note this has also been cross-posted to [Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?zottffssentettffssen) (by me)</sup>

Comment: this could even be well defined to go on infinitely as a sequence challenge; the main issues with number->word challenges have nothing to do with the very first letter :P

Comment: I thought this was some fake German word.

Comment: @OskarSkog I would have bet on some real city in Iceland. :-p

Comment: Hahah! When I clicked this "episode" of CG I expected the title to be some long German word meaning maybe **headache** or **the number of hours until next Tuesday.** I'm no code jockey, but I occasionally peruse code golf Q&A.  This is to marvel at both the skillsets and the creative forces in both creating the puzzles and solving them.  I clearly don't read / speak German either.  :,)

Comment: Well then. Neither Oskar's comment nor Arnauld's were visible when I made my first one.  I'd have likely phrased it a bit differently if I'd realized I'm essentially composing a verbose "me too."

Comment: @zedmelon c'est la vie. Enjoy your visit and marvel at the golfers :-)

Comment: It does look like the concatenation of "Zott" (german dairy company), "fressen" (devour) and "entfesseln" (unleash). At least when you glance over the title :D

Comment: @QBrute So I expect it's similar to the titles of at least half a dozen German adult films?  With "devour" and "unleash" that's a given--but by adding "milk" too?  Well, that's just the cherry on top, if you'll pardon the expression.

Comment: @thejonymyster Thanks buddy.  I marvel every time.

Comment: @py3programmer https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/c-est-la-vie

Answer (score 23):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 58 bytes

```python
a='ttffssen'
print(f"zo{a}te{a+''.join(x*10for x in a)}o")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rRJt1UtK0tKKi1Pz1LkKijLzSjTSlKryqxNrS1KrE7XV1fWy8jPzNCq0DA3S8osUKhQy8xQSNWvzlTShJuRBNAH1wMwpSYWzsIA0LKAYC0iFgzw4gNsKcz8A)

Comment: Damn it, beat by Steffan because of the outage :(

Answer (score 13):

## x86-64 machine code, 41 bytes

```
66 B8 7A 6F 66 AB 48 B8 74 74 66 66 73 73 65 6E 48 AB AA C6 07 65 AE 48 AB 6A 0A 59 F3 AA 48 C1 E8 08 75 F5 B0 6F 66 AB C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZFLT8MwEITP8a8Ygqo4EKryFOqDA4gjEqo4gNoeXMdujFI72ClNW/jrBIfwuuxqd0bfjrT8aMF5XTO3BMU4pKS7yM2c5ZBE9oOleQWrEkTbCG@ITDQcXpLAlcatSdCdb0qBXnV2mfh67YUuc1wphGUppXNCh633pW1z8sW7fnq4xf3DGBObqplni8jrnDV667b9oFi5DMe9AQpTwPKKBFYU@Ka4zMI2sfzJZ72FbcEsT5qIv/msKEkcIh6QV6NSSMozZg/g/ILsK83zVSowdGWqTDe7IkTpEkumNI3JjgSNGVa4VV5Ozo9PZgMSSNrOHhAU1tslDTsuTPC3/hOm@o7xTGkBblLRDxu1uVBhhF6CjR9Tg92PHZ3eyaNHbUaUrrRTCy1SfAWOZTypDg9n8eAd60zlAnSDPQ@pbk7/JwHtKDQvcfFUe1Llxfe6/uAyZwtXHy0vznzxjx55v8g/AQ)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI a memory address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov ax, 'z' | 'o'<<8    # Put these two bytes in AX.
    stosw                   # Write them to the string, advancing the pointer.
    .byte 0x48, 0xB8        # Place the following eight bytes in RAX.
    .ascii "ttffssen"
    stosq                   # Write them to the string, advancing the pointer.
    stosb                   # Write the first byte 't' again, advancing the pointer.
    mov BYTE PTR [rdi], 'e' # Place the byte 'e' at the current output address.
    scasb                   # Advance RDI over the 'e' while comparing with AL.
    stosq                   # Write "ttffssen" again, advancing the pointer.
r:  push 10; pop rcx        # Set RCX to 10.
    rep stosb               # Write AL to the string 10 times, advancing the pointer.
    shr rax, 8              # Shift RAX right by 8 bits; AL (its low byte)
                            #  will be each of "ttffssen" in order.
    jnz r                   # Jump back, to repeat, if the result is nonzero.
    mov al, 'o'             # Set AL to 'o'.
    stosw                   # Write 'o' and a null byte, advancing the pointer.
    ret                     # Return.
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
₁ʀ∆ċvhṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoHKgOKIhsSLdmjhuYUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

```
₁ʀ∆ċvhṅ
₁ʀ      # Range [0, 100]
  ∆ċ    # Nth cardinal of each
    vh  # First char of each
      ṅ # Join together
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sMH`, 4 bytes

```
ƛ∆ċh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzTUgiLCIiLCLGm+KIhsSLaCIsIiIsIiJd)

(thanks to lyxal)

sMH, why are there flags for everything

```
H flag  # Preset stack to 100
ƛ       # Map over 100
M flag  # Make that 100 be a range [0, 100] instead of [1, 100]
 ∆ċ     # Convert to cardinal
   h    # Get the first character
s flag  # Join together
```

Comment: 5 with the right set of flags: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJNcyIsIiIsIuKCgcab4oiGxItoIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: @lyxal I know, but I wanted a flagless solution. Might as well post though

Comment: 4, if your flags represent how some people would respond to them: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzTUgiLCIiLCLGm+KIhsSLaCIsIiIsIiJd)

Answer (score 8):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.text.english`, 39 bytes

```factor
[ 100 [0,b] [ number>text first ] map ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU2r0GBPP3crhezUorzUHIXi1MLS1Lzk1GKF3MSSDL2S1IoSvdS89JzM4gyISFFiXjpQNjNfwXppaUmarsVN9WgFQwMDhWgDnaRYhWiFvNLcpNQiO5BOhbTMouIShVigzgKFWIjyVcmJOTkK5UWZJakQgQULIDQA)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

Builds the output recursively from right to left.

```javascript
f=(k=8)=>k>0?f(k-.1)+`${s}o`[~~k]:`zo${s="ttffssen"}te`+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYj29ZC09Yu287APk0jW1fPUFM7QaW6uDY/IbquLjvWKqEqH8i1VSopSUsrLk7NU6otSU3QLv6fk1qikFpRkJpckpqiYKugVJUPU1GSCmdhAWlYQDEWkAoHeXCQr2TNBbK3KLUYaGWahqY1V3J@XnF@TqpeTn66BlBYByJni3CavYL6@x39j@ZMAZLqClYK6o/m9qhrWv8HAA)

#### Note

Because of floating point errors, we don't reach exactly `k = 0` on the last iteration. That's why we have to use the test `k > 0 ?` instead of just `k ?`.

This is still 1 byte shorter than the following integer version:

**58 bytes**

```javascript
f=(k=81)=>k--?f(k)+`${s}o`[k/10|0]:`zo${s="ttffssen"}te`+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYj29bCUNPWLltX1z5NI1tTO0Glurg2PyE6W9/QoMYg1iqhKh8oYqtUUpKWVlycmqdUW5KaoF38Pye1RCG1oiA1uSQ1RcFWQakqH6aiJBXOwgLSsIBiLCAVDvLgIF/Jmgtkb1FqMdDKNA1Na67k/Lzi/JxUvZz8dA2gsA5EzhbhNHsF9fc7@h/NmQIk1RWsFNQfze1R17T@DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <sup>49 48</sup> 41 bytes

```
IntegerName@#~StringPart~1&~Array~100<>""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Zl@98zryQ1PbXILzE31UG5LrikKDMvPSCxqKTOUK3OsagosbLO0MDAxk5J6X8AUKrEIe0/AA)

*-1 thanks to Steffan*

*-7 thanks to att!*

My Wolfram is rusty and was never great, so probably golfable, but it seemed like the right tool.

TIO shows an error because it can't connect to the internet, but it's still prints the correct answer.

Comment: `StringPart[#,1]` => `#~StringPart~1`. The TIO error is because it uses mathematica's libraries and TIO doesn't have access to internet.

Comment: [Try it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fc2294be-f31f-42ce-b1e2-62a09c424a2b) (use [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/fc2294be-f31f-42ce-b1e2-62a09c424a2b) link if you're logged in and want to edit the code)

Comment: @Steffan Thanks.  I was surprised I couldn't use `Part` (`[[`) there to extract first char -- or that there was no other shortcut.

Comment: Yep, `String`s are atoms, and all the `String...` overhead is part of what makes golfing string-based challenges annoying. [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Zl@98zryQ1PbXILzE31UG5LrikKDMvPSCxqKTOUK3OsagosbLO0MDAxk5J6X8AUKrEIe0/AA) (or [46](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/9@xqCixMtozryQ1PbXILzE31UG5LrikKDMvPSCxqKTOUE3H0MBAx1AnAChUEvv/PwA) explicitly printing).

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 145 bytes

```
--[----->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<]++++++++[->++>+>>>++>++>>+<<<<<<<<]>++++.>+.+++++..>.>.>---.>---.>-.>.<<+.->.[<]>------[.>]<[<]>[..........>]<+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU1RCoBQCDuQuBPILiLvo4Iggj6Czm/6eBVt4JgbOp/TdqzXskeouhYof9pAkwHPSiXskvpVWDko6EWAxbz5jLRmAiU8y/2dOtisrONFbgQRNw)

**Commented code**

```
--[----->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<]    Set cell 0 to 254 and loop 102 times filling cells 1 to 8 with ascii f
++++++++[->++>+>>>++>++>>+<<<<<<<<]  Set cell 0 to 8 and loop 8 times boosting certain cells to give vnffvvfn 
>++++.                               Move to cell 1; boost and output z
>+.+++++..                           Move to cell 2; boost and output ott
>.>.>---.>---.>-.>.                  From cells 3 to 8 output ffssen modifying values as necessary
<<+.->.                              Move to cell 6; temporarily modify to output t; move to cell 7 to output e
[<]>------                           Move to cell 1 and modify from z to t; cells now contain ttffssen
[.>]                                 Move through ttffssen outputing each character once (12 to 19) until empty cell reached
<[<]>                                Move back to cell 1
[..........>]                        Move through ttffssen outputting each character 10 times (20 to 99) 
<+.                                  Move to cell 8; modify value to o and output
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
print('zottffssentettffssen'+'t'*20+'f'*20+'s'*20+'e'*10+'n'*10+'o')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcY7DoBACAXA4zzdbfycCaINbOQ1enk0IVYz4@bhtmeO6zROeJxUjRCj/EMH0balQ4soBG39sMIxZ74)

I'm sure this isn't optimal. Idk.

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 59 bytes

```
s/^/ttffssen/
s/./&&&&&&&&&&/g
s/.*/zottffssentettffssen&o/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhY3rYv14_RLStLSiotT8_S5ivX19NXgQD8dJKClX5UPU1GSCmOp5etDjICatGAhF4QBAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [`english`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/english/index.html), <strike>48</strike> 50

*Edited per Dominic van Essen's comment*

```
cat(substr(english::as.english(0:100),1,1),sep="")
```

Similar to [chunes' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252595/87572), this solution uses a library / package to handle integer-to-English mapping, then parses and collapses the resulting vector.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Welcome from me, too.  You can shorten the code a bit by using ```cat(,sep="")``` instead of ```paste(,collapse="")```, but unfortunately it's generally required to include the code to load a library in the byte-count (using ```library()``` or ```::```), [like this](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=cat(substr(english%3A%3Aas.english(0%3A100)%2C1%2C1)%2Csep%3D%22%22))...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 5):

## [Arturo](https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo), <sub><s>110</s></sub> <sub><s>65</s></sub> 63 bytes

- **-45 bytes**, -2 bytes thanks to Krenium

```
s:"ttffssen"print~{zo|s|te|s||join map split s=>[repeat&10]|o}
```

Readable version:

```
s: "ttffssen"
print ~{zo|s|te|s||join map split s => [repeat&10]|o}
```

[Try it Online!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?pmwgLs)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, and nice first answer!

Comment: Great job! Well done!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
s["zo"J"ttffssen""te"Js*LTJ\o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72koLIkY8GCpaUlaboWe4ujlarylbyUSkrS0oqLU_OUlEpSlbyKtXxCvGLyIWqgSmFaAA)

A near literal translation of [97.100.97.109](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/113573/97-100-97-109)'s [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252599/78186).

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```ruby
puts"zo#{a="ttffssen"}te#{a+a.chars.map{|c|c*10}*''}o"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFipKl@5OtFWqaQkLa24ODVPqbYkFSignaiXnJFYVKyXm1hQXZNck6xlaFCrpa5em6/0/39VPkx1SSqchQWkYQHFWEAqHOTBQT4A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
say+zo,$_=ttffssen,te.$_.s/./$&x10/gre.o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYK1QnFipoFSVX1KSllZcnJpXkgpnYQFpWEAxFpAKB3lwkK9k/R9omXZVvo5KvC3MFp2SVD2VeL1ifT19FbUKQwP99KJUvfz//wE)

Comment: Can shave a byte by using commas instead of dots: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKpKl9JRyXetqQkLa24ODVPpyQVyNUp1tfTV1GrMDTQTy9K1cn//9/Q9F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali – nice! one byte shaved.

Comment: `'zo'` can be `+zo`.

Comment: @dingledooper – sure can! thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>106</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>77</s></sup> 75 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=0;i<101;i++)putchar("zottffssentettffssen"[i>99?:i<20?i:i/10]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dCsIwDIXvfYpQEFrncFO82ObPhfgUzotRWw1qN9aKw7FXt1Y2RWEfBBKSnORwn18ydbRWUmS1zEuKyyDBRRiECXoeK26Gn7KSkkdujJRaC2XEJyM7XEXROsbFNFhjjJMw2LOksagMXDNUlEE9AMdbYgSiKgQ34gBL6JUzPcgedA/ii/qSk6S9nittuh/4SfCzKHd790RN0mo7Tato42JOxvBbz0jTbhelsyMp8TtWQFjbkZT9j6Rq21mMYahT5SQ/nt1kY59cXrKjtv79BQ)

*Saved a whopping <s>22</s> <s>28</s> 30 bytes thanks to [jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)!!!*
*Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Comment: @jdt Oops, well spotted - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

Identical to my (and **[@xnor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)**, presumably) Python solution to the **[cross-post](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?zottffssentettffssen)** on Anarchy Golf.

```python
s='ttffssen'
print'zo%ste'%s+s+(('o'+s*10)*8)[-8::-8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcs9CoAwDEDh3XuU9IeCOpWCJxHHFF2aYrLo5eNkp37TW1575KS6qvIGIqUwY4Wp3VcVeMmwIBgOHKwFgsB@mZ1Pbo8p55gO1Zf@S7DXQBngAexqRx8)

Comment: I really like the idea of mul + slicing to repeat each character.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 68 bytes

```lua
a='ttffssen'print('zo'..a..'te'..a..a:gsub('.',('%1'):rep(10))..'o')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAwDAXQ08hPQIJdCx4mQiuCtKVNFy8fBbc3vHuqu@4wy3mMVND6VYzwVIioCCz90HiOeRAEK2EJ4NhTo7Axf6mC3V8)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash 5.2, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Sisyphus*

```bash
ttffssen
echo zo$_\te$_${_//?/&&&&&&&&&&}o
```

Uses the **[brand new](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.2#n86)** (set-by-default) shell option `patsub_replacement`!
Look forward to seeing this in many a future Bash golf.

ATO is still on 5.1 at the time of writing, so if you want to try it out yourself, the easiest way is with `alpine:edge`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
podman run --rm -i alpine:edge << 'EOF'
apk add bash >/dev/null
bash -c 'ttffssen;echo zo$_\te$_${_//?/&&&&&&&&&&}o'
EOF
```

Comment: I don't have bash 5.2 at hand, but I think removing the `x=` and using the topic variable `$_` should work.

Comment: That it does! I have a tendency to forget that one, since `<<<$_` in Zsh always outputs `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>29</s> 26 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`zottffÑA`
+h`` +¢®pAÃ+'o
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YHpvdHRmZtFBYAoraGCSYCAroq5wQcMrJ28)

Note that there is an unprintable character between the ``` `` ``` on line 2

```
`zottffÑA`     # U = "zottffssen"
               # Start building the output with U implicitly
 h``           # Replace the first 2 characters of U with "te"
+              # Add that to the output
      ¢        # Remove the first 2 characters of U
       ®  Ã    # For each remaining character
        pA     #  Duplicate it 10 times
     +         # Add that to the output
           +'o # Add "o" to the output
               # Print implicitly
```

I also tried [another version](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YHR0ZmbRQWAKInpvIitVK2CSYCtVK3BBIPM4IKwrJ28) which does "U repeated 10 times, grouped by index % 8, then joined" for the 20-99 portion, but it didn't golf as well

Comment: [26 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YHpvdHRmZtFBYAoraGCSYCAroq5wQcMrJ28)

Comment: @Shaggy Nice, I always struggle to find ways to make the interpreter insert `U` for me.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>77</s> 71 bytes

<sup>Saved 6 bytes thanks to [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252593/zottffssentettffssen/252739?noredirect=1#comment562329_252739)</sup>

```
=LET(a,"ttffssen",CONCAT("zo",a&"te"&a,REPT(MID(a,ROW(1:8),1),10),"o"))
```

This is only slightly more efficient than just typing the 101 characters manually.

- `LET(a,"ttffssen"` stores the string `ttffssen` for later repeated use.
- `CONCAT("zo",a&"te"&a` combines strings to make the first part. This is only 2 bytes more efficient than hard-coding it.
- `MID(a,ROW(1:8),1)` turns the 8 character string into an array of 8 characters.
- `REPT(MID(~),10)` repeats each of those characters 10 times. These last two lines are the big byte-saver I missed the first time. Storing the string as `a` is not efficient by itself but it *is* if you later re-use it in the `REPT()` function.
- `CONCAT(~,~,~,"o")` add the last letter to the rest of the bits.

---

Original 77 byte version:

```
="zottffssentettffssen"&CONCAT(REPT({"t","f","s","e","n"},5*{4,4,4,2,2}))&"o"
```

---

This **78 byte** alternative looked like it'd be shorter since each character is repeated the same number of times (allowing you to replace an array with a single integer) but it's only a close second:

```
="zottffssentettffssen"&CONCAT(REPT({"t","f","s"},20))&"eeeeeeeeeennnnnnnnnno"
```

---

This **79 byte** alternative was an attempt at compressing that array of characters but the savings where offset by the bytes required to convert them to strings:

```
="zottffssentettffssen"&CONCAT(REPT(CHAR(101+{15,1,14,0,9}),5*{4,4,4,2,2}))&"o"
```

Comment: ++. I gave it a shot and ended up with `=LET(a,"ttffssen",CONCAT("zo",a&"te"&a,REPT(MID(a,ROW(1:8),1),10),"o"))` which would be 71 bytes. I guess it's the Excel equivalent to the most voted [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252599/100057) so far =)

Comment: You can save 1 byte by changing `REPT(MID(a,ROW(1:8),1),10)` to `MID(a,LEFT(ROW(10:89)),1)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), <del>301</del> 57 bytes

saved bytes thanks to the comment of @Sisyphus

Golfed version provided by me, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcsxDoAgDEbhq/whxE0vRBjUFBdCjS0J4fI4GDvxTW95euYx7qqCzkFI0aCakgiVqORbeOiSemDdc8YG37CYyN/pOv@PktVEmpAJMsWwGy8)

```
puts zo[set x ttffssen]te$x[regsub -all . $x &&&&&&&&&&]o
```

Original ungolfed version

```
set a "ttffssen"

proc repeat_string {str count} {
    set result ""
    for {set i 0} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        append result $str
    }
    return $result
}

proc generate_string {a} {
    set result ""
    foreach char [split $a ""] {
        append result [repeat_string $char 10]
    }
    return $result
}

puts "zo${a}te${a}[generate_string $a]o"
puts "zottffssentettffssenttttttttttttttttttttffffffffffffffffffffsssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeennnnnnnnnno"
```

Comment: Nice. I think you can use a regsub to get much shorter - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcsxDoAgDEbhq/whxE0vRBjUFBdCjS0J4fI4GDvxTW95euYx7qqCzkFI0aCakgiVqORbeOiSemDdc8YG37CYyN/pOv@PktVEmpAJMsWwGy8 "Tcl – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•p≠²δK•ÐST×JŠ"zoÿteÿÿo
```

Port of [*@97.100.97.109*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252599/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDooJHnQsObTq3xRvIPjwhOOTwdK@jC5Sq8g/vL0k9vP/w/vz//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
.•p≠²δK•           # Push compressed string "ttffssen"
 Ð                 # Triplicate it
  S                # Convert the top copy to a list of characters
   T×              # Repeat each character 10 times as string
     J             # Join these back together to a single string
      Š            # Triple-swap so the other two strings are on top
       "zoÿteÿÿo  "# Push string "zoÿteÿÿo", where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with
                   # the three strings
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•p≠²δK•` is `"ttffssen"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 44 bytes

```
zo_te_20$*t20$*f20$*s10$*e10$*no
_
ttffssen
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fqyo/viQ13shARasERKSBiGJDIJEKIvLyueK5SkrS0oqLU/P@/wcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Mostly run-length compression via `$*`, with a final substitution to save a further 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔ttffssenθzoθteθＦθ×ιχo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DqaQkLa24ODVPSUehUNOaK6AoM69EQ6kqXwnOQRIuSUUVTssvUgAyFCAiIZm5qcUamToKhgaaCD0gk/7//69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ttffssenθ
```

Save the first letters of two/twelve/twenty, three/thirteen/thirty, four(teen)/forty, five/fifteen/fifty, six(teen/ty), seven(teen/ty), eight(een/y) and nine(teen/ty) in a variable.

```
zo
```

Output the first letters of zero and one.

```
θ
```

Output the first letters of two to nine.

```
te
```

Output the first letters of ten and eleven.

```
θ
```

Output the first letters of twelve to nineteen.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over the first letters of twenty to ninety.

```
×ιχ
```

Output each letter repeated ten times.

```
o
```

Output the first letter of one [hundred].

Answer (score 2):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 64 bytes

Just uses the same method as plenty of answers.

```
out"zo"$A="ttffssen""te"$A;each$A as$v;for$_ in0..9out$v;out'o'
```

Outputs the expected string, without any trailing whitespace.

## Ungolfed

Extremely verbose, almost looking like pseudo-code:

```
Set $initials to the value "ttffssen".
Show the values "zo", $initials, "te", $initials.

Loop through $initials as $letter.
Begin.
    Loop from 0 to 9 as $i.
    Begin.
        Show the contents of $letter.
    End.
End.

Show the value "o".
```

More code-y looking:

```
$initials = "ttffssen";
echo "zo", $initials, "te", $initials;

each $initials as $letter {
    for $i in 0..9 {
        echo $letter;
    }
}

echo "o";
```

All versions do exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╢├╕◄ε╕f♣+∙╢►@♂m*'o
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EWPpsx5NHXqo@kt57YC6bRHMxdrP@qYCZKYtsvh0cymXC31/P//AQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
╢├        # Push compressed "zo"
╕◄ε       # Push compressed "ttff"
   ╕f♣    # Push compressed "ssen"
      +   # Append the top two together: "ttffssen"
       ∙  # Triplicate it
╢►        # Push compressed "te"
  @       # Triple-swap the top three values (a,b,c to c,a,b)
 m        # Map over the characters of the top "ttffssen":
♂ *       #  Repeat the character 10 times
'o       '# Push character "o"
          # (after which the entire stack is joined and output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```powershell
"zo$(($a='ttffssen'))te$a$(-join($a|% T*y|%{"$_"*10}))o"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwEETvfsWybElSKOi14kn6B9411C0qpWmbiFrrt0erNSL0nZadYWe2Nhdu7YHL0hNfa84d72EFojPOFYW1XDkO0wTFBHYCDlQBI5ZAecv6nbnz2BmSkvRKfBOFUo5Jk0xO5li9pD6CTXzrozvSFuPF/KGUQY/Z2DwFkuENhTNcf66nMAhj1LDPmrMu/9yQcAM/i38C)

```powershell
"zo                                                    " # start s new string with "zo"
   $(               )                                    # evaluate the subexpression $(...), which ...
     ($a='ttffssen')                                     # ... sets $a to "ttffssen", and outputs it straight back into the string (because of the additional brackets)
                     te                                  # literal "te"
                       $a                                # insert $a ("ttffssen")
                         $(                          )   # insert the results of another subexpression $(...)
                                 $a|% T*y                # pipe $a to % (alias for ForEach-Object) and call the member ToCharArray()
                                         |%{       }     # pipe the single characters to % and process them in the scriptblock {...}; loop variable is $_
                                            "$_"*10      # turn the char back into a string, and "multiply" it with 10
                           -join(                   )    # join those 10-char-long strings together
                                                      o  # Add the final "one hundred"
```

Output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 92 bytes

Interesting challenge!

```java
()->{var s="ottffssente";for(int i=0;i<90;)s+=++i==9?"":s.charAt(i<9?i:i/10%9);return"z"+s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBToQwEIbv@xSTSUxoyCIeoVbifT15NB4qlN2uLGCnEN0NR28@gr7cvgiWyOKa4H@aTmf@/0u7la1cbrPnvm6eCp1CWkgiuJO6hMNiAaBLq0wuUwUr1wCne2t0uYbcY9ydu2GIrLRudwUFiN5jy5tDKw2QwMraPCdSzgR5XhnP2YEWIdfXUcgZ@cL3tRBRghhTkG6kubWeu0t0rC@vwouIcaNsY0rco0@86/kQN6KOqW2lM9g5YO@H7OERpFkT@4urXmuVWpWBANyfYU3VjPIZ0YzUpHJShfw83ihyyUUwvprrv5FVu6BqbFC7CVuU3gnx/wnn4iOgPxSBemlkQb9bCR4/3zHG49cHstPfdP03)

---

I'm really glad that it was possible to beat the trivial solution :') (**95 bytes**) :

```java
()->"zottffssentettffssen"+"t".repeat(20)+"f".repeat(20)+"s".repeat(20)+"eeeeeeeeeennnnnnnnnno"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`zo{=`ttffÑA`}{+mpA}o
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YHpvez1gdHRmZtFBYH2SeyttcEF9bw)

```
`zo{=`ttffÑA`}\x92{+mpA}o
`zo                     o     :Compressed string, starting with "zo" and ending with "o"
   {                          :Interpolate
    =                         :  Assign to variable U
     `ttffÑA`                 :  Compressed string "ttffssen"
             }                :End interpolation
              \x92            :Compressed "te"
                  {    }      :Interpolate
                   +          :  Append to U
                    m         :  Map each character in U
                     p        :    Repeat
                      A       :    Ten times
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 97 bytes

```
select 'z'||listagg(substr(to_char(to_date(level,'J'),'jsp'),1,1))from"DUAL"connect by level<=100
```

Or, a bit more readable:

```
select
   'z' ||
   listagg(
      substr(
         to_char(to_date(level, 'J'), 'jsp')
         ,1,1)
      )
from
  "DUAL"
connect by
   level<=100;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 59 bytes

```
;O+'zo'+=a'ttffssen'+'te'+a'\';Wa;O+*A Aa 10'\'=aSaF1''O'o'
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7Tysnem8nKz1hJ3R0ZmZzc2VuJysndGUnK2EnXFwnO1dhO08rKkEgQWEgMTAnXFwnPWFTYUYxJydPJ28nIiwiIiwiMi4wIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
~s="zo$(a="ttffssen")te$(a*prod([a...].^10))o"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67YVqkqX0Uj0VappCQtrbg4NU9JsyQVKKBVUJSfohGdqKenF6sXZ2igqZmv9L@gKDOvRKPO0BakC6ahJBXOwgLSsIBiLCAVDvLgIF9J8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 38 bytes

```
echo'zo',(,'te','o',~[,10&#)'ttffssen'
```

Nothing new here...

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWN9VSkzPy1avy1XU0dNRLUtV11IHMumgdQwM1ZU31kpK0tOLi1Dx1iGqoJphmAA)

```
echo'zo',(,'te','o',~[,10&#)'ttffssen'
                            'ttffssen'  NB. str literal
         (                 )            NB. monadic train
                       10&#             NB. repeat each char 10 times
                     [,                 NB. append , to input [
                'o',~                   NB. appends 'o' to result using ~
           'te',                        NB. append result to 'te'
          ,                             NB. append result to input
    'zo',                               NB. append result to 'zo'
echo                                    NB. print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 40 bytes

```
“¡Œb»
Ñ;¢x⁵
“¡Ph%»Ḥ
“¡çı»;¢1£“ŀu»¢1£2£”o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6Fjc9HjXMObTw6KSkQ7u5Dk-0PrSo4lHjVi6wYECG6qHdD3csgfAOLz-y8dBuoALDQ4uBAkcbSg_tBnOMQPy5-UuKk5KLoabCTAcA)

Basically just a couple of compressed strings, repeating some of them